# Unhinged: How to have reversable storage of excess mercury

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

After centrifuging a large amount of redstone, we're left with at least a stack of mercury cells. Is there anyway of emptying those cells and saving the mercury for later?

Any method that consumes the cells isn't acceptable, and we should be able to put mercury back in the cells later.

(Running Unhinged, so be aware that some things are more expensive than others. If the only answer is a liquid tesseract, I might just give up. :P )

Comment: does a liquid transposer remove the mercury?

Comment: @ratchetfreak yeah, it does. You want to answer this question with that answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a liquid transposer to remove the mercury without losing the cells

it can also fill them back up again